# error Execution failed for task react-native-vector-icons while running

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I want to use react-native vector icons but while I run the application it gives an error.

I use the Ubuntu 16.4 and I build react-native android app

Error is like this:
react-native-vector-icons:mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:react-native-vector-icons:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
:react-native-vector-icons:processReleaseResources
/home/nikunj/Android/Sdk/build-tools/26.0.1/aapt: 1: /home/nikunj/Android/Sdk/build-tools/26.0.1/aapt: Syntax error: ")" unexpected

:react-native-vector-icons:processReleaseResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':react-native-vector-icons:processReleaseResources'.

  > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 26.601 secs
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/android-setup.html

Comment: What is the version of your `react-native` and `react-native-vector-icons`?

Comment: react-native version is 0.47.2 and react-native-vector-icons version is 4.3.0